# How would one hash a string so that if a char is modified anywhere it would hardly change?

Tags: java, hash

Take this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("1000000".hashCode());
    System.out.println("1000001".hashCode());
    System.out.println("2000000".hashCode());
}
```

This produces the output

```
1958013297
1958013298
-1449450318
```

The first one is the 'control'.  In the second I change one of the characters and it produces a very similar hash, however if i modify one character at the beginning it gives me a completely different hash.  Is there a way to make it so that it wouldn't affect the range  of hashes whether you change a character at the beginning or end of the string?

Comment: The `String` class is `final`. What way are you thinking about?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use `hashCode` in a manner for which it was not intended. Can you give more information about your real goals here?

Comment: You could use `module` that means `%` for example if i would want to limit the result to 0-9 i would use `255%10` this would give me: `5`

Comment: Given an instance of string with a known hash code, it's not difficult to determine how any particular change to the string will affect the hash code.  The hash code method that was chosen for strings was designed, however, so that different strings are unlikely to have the same hash code by chance.  This requires that many similar strings have substantially-different hash codes.  What are you doing such that that would not be a good thing?

Comment: @supercat Simulating evolution(kinda), I append all the values of the nodes in a creatures brain to a string and then take the hash of it to show its 'species'.  It is a very important part of the program as it decides whether two animals can mate and whether they can fight.

Comment: @Ryxuma: The idea is that each animal has some number of properties encoded into a string, and you wish to be able to derive a number from the string such that one can examine two numbers and determine whether differences are apt to be significant or slight?  How many properties are you interested in?

Comment: @supercat there are 10-30 integers representing the nodes for each animal

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is probably not a good idea, as it will cause hashes of unrelated strings to cluster. This will cause poor performance in hash tables and will give lots of collisions in other contexts.

That said, there are many simple solutions for this. You could add all the numeric values of the characters together, which would make minor changes only affect the hash a bit (but would give *terrible* dispersion). As an extreme case, you could make everything hash to 0, which would make the hash not change when anything changes.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It is not a very good idea to use a *hash* here, as hashes are commonly designed to differ as much as possible, if only a single bit of the input changes (Java string is evidently not doing a very good job here - but it is also [very simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29#The_java.lang.String_hash_function)). This is sometimes called an avalanche effect in hash implementations.

What you could use is some distance metric instead of hash, such as [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). Alternately you can try to sort the characters in the string and hash that (but that will likely give similar hashes even for quite different strings).

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are computed in a veriety of ways; most methods involve *prime numbers* and a recurrent formula for each member of a structure/class/whathaveyou. Changing a character at the beginning of a String will dramatically change your hash value (as in, you wouldn't notice that two Strings differ by one character just by looking at their hashcodes).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for one-way hash encoding ? If this is the case you should try a base 64 encoded SHA256 hash:

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = digest.digest("This is string".getBytes("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(hash));
```

This returns:

- `1rx2SBPZH729fp91Vkx/bC2DD1dNdwA0i1NJiYOO+WQ=` *for* **"This is string"**
- `ld5Z0dyXI2k3oxkUqw62lQwa2kmqtfH28/nGagnx7bM=` *for* **"This is strong"**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds from your comment as though what you really want is a means of converting small groups of integers into "digests", such that examining the digests of two such groups will indicate whether they are likely to be similar.  If you aren't limited to using a 32-bit digest, I would suggest that a 64-bit one could reduce the false-positive rate.

To give a more specific example, suppose that one wishes to produce a 64-bit digest from 6 numbers, and be able to--by comparing two things' digests, be able to reject any pairs of things other than those which match perfectly, match five of the six items, or are within 1 on two items.  Define 12 ways of mapping integers to numbers from 0 to 63, such that the mapping is as well-scrambled as practical.

Then compute

```
Digest = (1L << Scramble(0  , (Value[0]  ) >> 1) |
         (1L << Scramble(0+6, (Value[0]+1) >> 1) |
         (1L << Scramble(1  , (Value[1]  ) >> 1) |
         (1L << Scramble(1+6, (Value[1]+1) >> 1) |
         (1L << Scramble(2  , (Value[2]  ) >> 1) |
         (1L << Scramble(2+6, (Value[2]+1) >> 1) |
         (1L << Scramble(3  , (Value[3]  ) >> 1) |
         (1L << Scramble(3+6, (Value[3]+1) >> 1) |
         (1L << Scramble(4  , (Value[4]  ) >> 1) |
         (1L << Scramble(4+6, (Value[4]+1) >> 1) |
         (1L << Scramble(5  , (Value[5]  ) >> 1) |
         (1L << Scramble(5+6, (Value[5]+1) >> 1);
```

That will yield a number with up to twelve of the bits set.  If two digests are close enough that the lists might be considered a near-match, the computation

```
long diff1 = digest1 & ~digest2;
diff1 &= (diff1-1);
diff1 &= (diff1-1);
```

should set `diff1` to zero, and a similar computation with `digest2 & ~digest1` should also yield zero.  Note that there will be many combinations of completely-different numbers whose digests will appear as "possible near matches", but this approach may make it possible to quickly reject a substantial majority of them.  If one repeated the `diff1 &=...` line another time or two, one could increase the tolerance further.  Note further that if `Scramble` returned values 0 to 31 rather than 0 to 63, the algorithm would be usable, somewhat, with an `int` digest, but the number of "false hits" would go up enormously unless the number of values combined into the digest were reduced.

If six values isn't enough, one could either add more bits (though that would increase the number of false hits), or one may be able to combine multiple values into each one by summing them together and scaling them down.  For example, if three numbers were summed together and one wanted things to match unless they were off by three, one could scale the sum down by a factor of eight [if everything matched except for two values which were off by three each, then the sum would be within six, which would mean that dividing the sum by eight would yield numbers that would be within one].